# Dynamically fetching a web page in a particular div of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I have a webpage wherein I want that onclick of a link or buttonn; the content of a particular div of webpage get updated and replaced with the content which I have scripted in other html page. How to do that?

Comment: If both pages are on same domain, you can do so via localstorage.

// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that .

```
<script>
function loaddata()
{ 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","page.html",true);
xhr.onload = function(){
if(this.readyState === 4)
{ 
var div = document.getElementById("divid"); // the div where you want to load the data 
div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
}
xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

html code

```
<button onclick="loaddata()">click</button>
<div id="divid"></div>
```

there are other ways to do that . but i have shown only javascript one 
hope this helps you what you are looking for

Comment: Nothing happen by this

Comment: You have to show your approach . Without your approach . how would anyone ever  understand that where you are stuck at actually .. show your code then .

Comment: It was minor mistake from my side...It worked perfectly fine..thank you so much..!!!